# Properties of a parsed JSON object are null

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, deserialization

I am using Json.NET  to deserialize the following JSON:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1234,
        "name": "Example",
        "coords": "[12:34]",
        "relationship": "ownCity"
    },
    {
        "id": 53,
        "name": "Another example",
        "coords": "[98:76]",
        "relationship": "ownCity"
    }
]
```

I'm trying to parse it to a List.

```
List<City> cities = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<City>>(json);
```

The definiton of the City class:

```
public class City
{
    int id { get; set; }
    string name { get; set; }
    string coords { get; set; }
    string relationship { get; set; }
}
```

The result is a list of two City objects, but all of their properties are null (id is 0).

Could anyone give me a heads up what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just so you know, the id is 0 because integer default value is 0, where as a string is a reference type, they will be null :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fields are all marked (by default) as private.
Change them to public or protected and it should work fine:

```
public class City
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string coords { get; set; }
   public string relationship { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will work for you

- You need to add public access level

The access level for class members and struct members, including nested classes and structs, is private by default.

- Or 
  You need DataContractAttribute to the class and DataMemberAttribute attribute to the members you want to serialize. As without [DataMember], you cannot serialize non-public properties or fields

[DataContract]
    public class City
    {

```
 [DataMember]
public int id { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public string name { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public string coords { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public string relationship { get; set; }
}
```